# Issue with '=>' after switching from PHP 7.0 to 7.2

Tags: php, session, php-7.2

I switch from php 7.0 to 7.2. After the change, code after the first "=>" was output to my page as text.

Reforming the text, removing portions of array, completely removing the array within the session_start. All that did was move the issue to the next "=>"

```
<? 
$file = __FILE__;
if (empty($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    $level = 'Security';
    $errorMessage = "[{$file}] [{$level}] Session cookie not passed".PHP_EOL;
    error_log($errorMessage);
    die();
} else {
    session_id($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
}
session_start([
    'gc_maxlifetime'    =>3600,
    'use_strict_mode'   =>1,
    'use_only_cookies'  =>1,
    'cookie_lifetime'   =>604800,
    'cookie_secure'     =>1,
    'cookie_httponly'   =>1
]);
//'cookie_samesite' =>1 add in after php 7.3
```

I expected that the session would start and the php would complete. The same as under php 7.0

What happened is that the code ran up to the first "=>". At that point it output "3600,'use_strict_mode'=>1, .... which ended at "?>"

In the apache2 error log I get a "Undefined variable: _SESSION in ....." which indicates that the session never started. No other error are displayed.

Comment: Tried creating an array prior to starting the session, assigning each key using "=". The session still was not created, but the text was not outputed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it was something in the php.ini file. I copied the php.ini file from the 7.0 folder to the 7.2 folder and everything started to work.